# Regex to remove block comments also removing * selector

Tags: regex, linux, bash, unix, sed

I am attempting to remove all block comments from .css files using bash.I have the following regex for a sed command:

```
sed -r '/\/(\*)*(\s)?(\w)*|(\*)(\s)?(\w)*/d'
```

This works fine stripping out block comments such as:

```
/**
* This is a comment
*/

/* this is another comment */
```

but it is also removing instances of the * Selector

```
* { 
     font-size: 10px;
     ...etc
  }
```

How could I alter the current regex to take this special case into account? Or will I need to rewrite my regex?

EDIT:
To clarify, the kinds of comments that I will encounter:

```
/**
* This is a comment
*/

/* This is another comment */

/* This is also 
valid
*/

/** "*/" as is { this } */
```

Comment: Does it have to be with sed ?

Comment: Preferably but i am open to suggestions, I would be willing to read up on awk or whatever else

Comment: `/** "*/" as is { this } */`: even if `*/` is enclosed between double quotes, it is always seen as a closing sequence. So the comment part is `/** "*/`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following `sed` command should work for you:

```
sed '/\/\*\**/{:a;/\*\//d;N;ba}' file.css
```

The command searches for the pattern `/**` or `/*` and if it was found, it executes the block of commands between the curly braces `{cmd1;cmd2;...}`. Inside that block I first define a label `:a`. In the next command I check if the pattern buffer contains the closing `*/`. If it was found I delete the pattern buffer and start the next cycle. Otherwise I append the next line of input to the patttern buffer through `N` and goto the label `a` through `ba`.

`file.css:`

```
/**
* This is a comment
*/
a {
    font-size: 10px;
}

/* This is another comment */
li {
    font-size: 12px;
}

/* This is also 
valid
*/
* {
    color:white;
}

/** "*/" as is { this } */
table {
    color:blue;
}
```

Output:

```
a {
    font-size: 10px;
}

li {
    font-size: 12px;
}

* {
    color:white;
}

table {
    color:blue;
}
```

Comment: That leaves `/* this is another comment */` line, need to remove a `*` ,`sed '/\/\*/{:a;/\*\//d;N;ba}'`

Comment: Beat me to it, it keeps the * selector but also keeps single line comments such as /* comment */

Comment: It didn't kept single line comments it just kept comments starting with `/*` instead od `/**`. I did that by intention since you stated that in your question. Edited it

Comment: @hek2mgl what are the :a; N;ba parts of the regex doing? A detailed explanation is not neccessary if you can point me to a decent guide on a site

Comment: `\**` makes the `*` optional, you should remove the quantifier `\*`

Comment: @jbailie1991 It is basically a loop. `:a` is a label, `N` get's a new line from input and appends it to the pattern buffer, `ba` jumps back to `a`.. `b` stands for *branch*

Comment: @hek2mgl ah i see, very interesting. looks like this is the start of my journey down the linux regex rabbit hole

Comment: @jbailie1991 Check this: http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html .. While it isn't the official documentation of `sed`, it is really useful. And this: http://sed.sourceforge.net/#sedlovers ! :)

Comment: @hek2mgl will do, much appreciated

Answer (score 2):

With awk

```
awk '!/\/?\*/||/{/'  file
```

#### Explanation

```
!/\/?\*/
```

`!` Means not
`//` Contain the regex
`\/?` 0 or 1 fwd slashes, needs to be escaped because `/` is delim to regex
`\*`Literal `*`

As a whole matches lines not beginning with `/*`

```
||
```

Or command used to link together statements, if the first command fails it will short circuit and not execute the second(not relevant here though)

```
/{/
```

If the line contains an open bracket then execute the command block

There is no command block and the default action is to print.

So as a whole the command `'!/^\/?\*/||/{/'` means if the line doesn't contain `/*` or `*` or it contains a `{` then print the line.

---

Incase comments contain `{`

```
awk '/\/\*/{x=1}!x;/\*\//{x=0}' file
```

#### Explanation

This one checks the line has `/*` and sets `x` to 1.
`!x` means print the line if x is 0 or null. It prints as it has no action block.
`x` is set back to 0 when `*/` is encountered.

---

#### Output

```
* {
     font-size: 10px;
     ...etc
  }
```

Doesn't take into account quoted stuff like `/* "*/" hello i'm still comment`

---

#### When it will break

`COMMAND`

```
awk '!/\/?\*/||/{/'
```

`FILE`

```
/*
I am comment that will print
*/
```

...

`COMMAND`

```
awk '/\/\*/{x=1}!x;/\*\//{x=0}'
```

`FILE`

```
/*
I wont print "*/"
I will print as the "*/" is seen as the end of the comment
This line prints
*/ ## This line will also print at x has not been set back to one
```

Comment: I would remove the `^`. Otherwise it would only remove comments which start at the beginning of a line.

Comment: @hek2mgl can `*` not appear anywhere else in the file and not be a comment ?

Comment: possibly with something like scss 

    .leftNav{
        width: 300px / 960px * 100%;
    }
But I think for what im working with this shouldn't be an issue

Comment: @jbailie1991 Probably best to use the second command then.I assume thats how comments work ?

Comment: There has been rare cases of it in some of the files I'm working in, and having created test comments in that style it works for those as well. Just as an aside, i put in a test comment :
 /* "*/" valid */
and it stripped it out as well, if thats what type of comment you meant at the end of the output segment

Comment: @JID Note, you are searching for `/*` not `*` . Check my example, your comment would leave `/* foobar */` in that case.

Comment: @hek2mgl are you sure? I tested this with a comment like the "this is another comment" type in my question and it removed it as well

Comment: @hek2mgl The second one shouldn't, i'll edit the first to remove the anchor to the start of the line.

Comment: @JID Yeah, also it is not a big deal, I just mentioned it. On the other hand it could also be a feature to leave comments which occur inside of rules...

Comment: @jbailie1991 I'll clarify when it wouldn't work in some examples at the, granted i don't know if they will even be valid syntax for css !

Comment: @hek2mgl It has nothing to do with whether it was in a rule, it was purely because there was whitespace before the `/*`

Comment: @jbailie1991 Do all comment lines(other than the first and last) have to begin with `*` ?

Comment: @JID oh no don't take that remark about the comment with double quotes as negative, it turns out the command strips it out as well as the other types of block comments which is all the better for me

Comment: @JID yes all of them will follow that style. I think im right in saying that without a * then that line is not a valid comment?

Comment: @jbailie1991 ha okay :) If you find any cases where it breaks, just let me know and i will amend the command.

Comment: @jbailie1991 I have no idea about the syntax of css !

Comment: @JID after a quick Google, it turns out i was wrong about the multiline comments, they dont have to start with a * between the opening and closing /. I will test the current solution with this type of comment

Comment: @JID Yes it removes those kinds of multiline comments as well. Your solution is proving to be fairly robust!

Answer (score 0):

The below code works for all the scenarios you provided

```
sed ':1;/^ *\/\*/{:2;/\*\/$/{d;b 1;};N;b 2;}' filename
```

Comment: Since you are new and writing interesting answers recently, consider using the `{}` section to format properly. Also, it is good practice to provide some kind of explanation instead of a mere "it works".

Comment: @fedorqui: Surely. Still struggling to understand what to use when and most importantly How :) Thanks!

Comment: @Dipak Why don't you think the sed solution which I've posted won't work for all scenarios? Basically your sed command looks too complicated.

Comment: @hek2mgl: The solution you provided will not work for a comment like "/* this "*/" is another comment
dipak*/" <Not to mention this may not be a real time scenario > :)

Comment: @Dipak I tested it on a comment as you posted above, it stripped it out as well

Comment: @jbailie1991 None of the solutions provided will remove the full comment from my second example in `When it will break`