# Remove comments in CSS using JS

Tags: javascript, css

I am using a desktop software to create small Websites. This software generates a style.css with some comments I would like to hide.

In the specific the comment I would like to hide is always at line 7.

There is a way to delete the comments automatically maybe in JS? Or do I have to do it manually every time?

Comment: This is quite vague, but you can run the CSS minifier of your choice, with the added benefit of some bandwidth saving.

Comment: As the comment is in a file brought in at runtime you will have to change that file in advance. @Álvaro González idea of using a minifier seems good if you are happy to get rid of all comments and have the file not as humanly readable as the original.

Comment: Would you like to run a bash script after generating the CSS file?

Comment: @HarshSaini not quite sure. Whats the pro?

Comment: @xagih, check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30211678/regex-to-remove-block-comments-also-removing-selector.

Answer (score 0):

The `/* */` comment syntax is used for both single and multiline comments. There is no other way to specify comments in external style sheets. However, when using the  element, you may use `<! -- -->` to hide CSS.